# Correct og:type for real estate website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm developing a website for a real estate agent and I'm trying to figure out which og:type to set for the properties.

I'd go with 'product', but I'm not quite sure because,..

1. „Please don't use them if your website just shows products that must be purchased on another site.“
   https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/places/
2. but: „This object type represents a product. This includes both virtual and physical products, but it typically represents items that are available in an online store.“
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/product/
3. I've checked some existing sites and they either use 'website', 'article' or nothing at all (which defaults to 'website' afaik).

Does it even matter? Is there a reason to not use 'product' for real estate properties?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Product is the right way to go right now.  Google and others are working to incorporate the real estate microdata on Schema.org but it's not there yet.  We've had good success using product though because Pinterest and sometimes Google will grab the price and show it as microdata.

Even Zillow, Trulia, and others use Product.